# When i use from IOC(UnityConfig) in Web API i can not call that constructor

Tags: c#, oop, asp.net-web-api2, ioc-container

when i use from IOC with unity container , i can call current method but my field is null because the default constructor is not called .

```
      public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();



        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, TestJirProjectContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IApplicationServiceTest, ApplicationServiceTest.ApplicationServiceTest>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        #region ApplicationService
        container.RegisterType<IPersonApplicationService, PersonApplicationService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IEntityMapper<Person, PersonDto>, PersonMapper>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        // 
        container.RegisterType<IBookApplicationService, BookApplicationService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IEntityMapper<Book, BookDto>, BookMapper>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        #endregion

        #region Services
        container.RegisterType<IPersonService, PersonService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IBookService, BookService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        #endregion

        #region Repositories
        container.RegisterType<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IBookRepository, BookRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        #endregion
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));


    }
}
```

also and my web APIconfig

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and also

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}

  public class BookController : ApiController
{
    public BookController()
    {

    }
    private readonly IApplicationServiceTest ApplicationService;

    public BookController(IApplicationServiceTest applicationService)
    {
        ApplicationService = applicationService;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public BookDto GetById()
    {
        int id = 1;
        var res = ApplicationService.GetById(id: id);
        return res;
    }
}
```

and when call this api controller my `ApplicationService` is null and i get error object reference is null in this line
 `ApplicationService.GetById(id: id);` 
In the other hand when i replace Controller with ApiController , It is work fine.

Comment: You forgot to replace Web API's `IDependencyResolver` with a custom one. You did replace MVC's `IDependencyResolver` but those are completely different things. You will now only be able to let Unity build MVC controllers, but not Web API controllers. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection#configuring-the-dependency-resolver).

Comment: @Steven Thank you . we should install `Unity.MVC5` and also `Unity.WebAPI`  then config this `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc5.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand (Do we need all this code to understand your problem?).
A principle of IoC design is to use the constructor to pass dependency and NOT have a second empty constructor that will simply instantiate / fetch that dependency (that would serve no purpose). So you need to call and pass the dependency every time you want to do it.

Edit: I don't see your BookController and its interface being added to the Unity container as well so since I'm not sure I understand your question, that may be also be why you're constructor with a dependency is not being called.

Comment: Ok ,I agree with you. I just want to say that the injection of dependency in the  mvc controller's is working properly, but not in the Web api-controller. By the way, I just installed unity.mvc5 , i think the problem is here